# is there a way to define if a word has only the "a" vowel?

Tags: function, haskell

im trying to make a function on haskell, I know that the function is define like:

```
justWithA : [Char] -> Bool
justWithA [] = True
justWithA (x:xs) | (x == "a") = x + justWithA xs                 
                 | else (x == "e") = False
                 | else (x == "i") = False
                 | else (x == "o") = False
                 | else (x == "u") = False
```

I think there is a better way to define this function, just don't know the correct way to do it...

Comment: You can't add a `Char` value (`x`) and a `Bool` value (returned by the recursive call to `justWithA`). What do you want to do, remove all vowels other than `a` or determine if there are vowels other than `a`, or something else?

Comment: What is `x + justWithA xs` supposed to do? Your function also only seems to work with strings of vowels.

Comment: Guards are not an `if` statement; you should drop all the `else` keywords.

Answer (score 5):

There are some problems with the current implementation:

- a guard does not use an `else` keyword;
- `x` is a `Char`, so you compare with `x == 'a'`, not <s>`x == "a"`</s>;
- `x + justWithA xs` makes no sense since `x` is a `Char` and you can not add a `Char` and `Bool` together; and
- your function will error if the string contains consonant, since these are not covered by any guard.

You can fix the function with:

```
justWithA : String -> Bool
justWithA [] = True
justWithA (x:xs)
    | x == 'a' = justWithA xs
    | x == 'e' = False
    | x == 'i' = False
    | x == 'o' = False
    | x == 'u' = False
    | otherwise = justWithA xs
```

we here only look for vowels and if there is a vowel that is `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`, then we return `False`.

We can simplify this to:

```
justWithA :: String -> Bool
justWithA = all (`notElem` "eiou")
```

or if you want to take uppercase into account as well:

```
justWithA :: String -> Bool
justWithA = all (`notElem` "eiouEIOU")
```